# how to prove roots quadratics

Tags: roots, quadratics

the quadratic equation $3(k+2)x^2+(k+5)x+k=0$ has real roots

show $(k-1)(11k+25) \geq 0 $

---

If $\Delta$ greater than $0$ it has real roots so,

$$\Delta = (k+5)^2 - 4 \cdot (3(k+2))\cdot k$$

$$k^2+10k+25-4(3k+6)\cdot k = (?)-12k^2-24k$$

which doesn't help and the answer is not the same for Wolfram|Alpha.

So how can I prove this is greater than $0$?

Comment: Is this $\Delta = (k+5)^2 - 4 * (3(3k+2))*k$ meant to be $\Delta = (k+5)^2 - 4 * (3(k+2))*k$?

Comment: that's an example of one sort of mistake i make all the time. i call them "mental short-circuits". can cause distress, and certainly wastes a lot of effort. don't know how i can curb the tendency. maybe a change of diet?

Comment: If you expand $b^2 - 4ac = (k + 5)^2 - 4 \cdot 3(k+2) \cdot k$, you get $-11k^2 + 14k - 25$, which is the opposite of your $(k - 1)(11k + 25)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think there are some mistakes in your working and perhaps your question isn't right. Here is mine:
\begin{align*}
\Delta&=(k+5)^2 - 4k(3(k+2))\\
&=k^2+10k+25-12k^2-24k\\
&=25-11k^2-14k\\
&=(11k+25)(1-k)
\end{align*}
Since there are real roots, we know that $\Delta\geq0$, hence we have $$(11k+25)(1-k)\geq0.$$